# Jenkins+WebDriver+Protractor: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm trying to setup jenkins to run my protractor tests.
I know that I need to run protractor without a browser. How do I setup it?

Which npm packages do I need to install?
My actual packages are (in package.json):

```
"devDependencies": {
"karma": "~0.12",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.2",
"karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1",
"protractor": "~2.1.0",
"bower": "~1.3.8",
"jasmine": "~2.3.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~0.3.5",
"karma-requirejs": "~0.2.2"
```

}

In my local machine everything works fine, because I see the chrome windows opening, and I see the tests happening on it.

But when I try to run it on Jenkins, I've got this messages:

**Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.**
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-24-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:593)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:139)
    ... 14 more
**Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.**
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-24-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:572)
    ... 19 more
**Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:4945/status] to be available after 20001 ms**
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:168)
    ... 21 more

My protractor.conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
// The address of a running selenium server.
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

// Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
        'args': ['incognito', 'disable-extensions', 'start-maximized', 'enable-crash-reporter-for-testing', '--test-type']
    },
    'loggingPrefs': {
        'browser': 'ALL'
    }
},

getPageTimeout: 20000,

    framework: 'jasmine2',

// Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
// protractor is called.

specs: ['global_setup.js', 'scenarios.js', 'campaign-grid-scenarios.js', 'create-campaign-scenarios.js'],
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:18090',

// Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
}
```

};

What is causing this timeout? Is that because webdriver is chrome but chrome cannot be opened in my jenkins setup?
I've been looking for similar questions but I didn't found anything related.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because chrome is not installed in your Jenkins setup. There are a couple of options for you depending on your situation.

1. If you have a standalone Jenkins instance and you know that you won't have any randomly selected nodes then you could use a headless browser implementation like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). All you need to make sure that `phantomjs` is installed on your Jenkins and tell your test to run on `phantomjs` instead of `chrome` like `browserName : 'phantomjs'`. You don't need to include phantomjs in your package.json. Just make sure that PhantomJS is installed and its executable is placed somewhere in the PATH.
2. Secondly you could setup a Selenium grid and setup nodes with different browsers you want to test. From Jenkins you run tests on the remote selenium grid on the browser of your choice. There are paid, third part options like sauce labs or browser stack if you wish to go that route.

Comment: I want to run it on a standalone Jenkins instance, and I know that headless browser like phantomjs is what I'm looking for. Could you be more explicit about the configurations that I have to do to get this scenario working? As you said, I should tell my tests to run on phantomjs. This means capabilities. browserName : 'phantomjs'? 
But before that I need to add 'phantomjs' to my 'package.json', right? And what else?
Thank you for your time, @nilesh.

Comment: Right, just tell browserName : 'phantomjs' and make sure PhantomJS is installed and in path on Jenkins server. No need to add anything to package.json. I updated the answer

Comment: Protractor official documentation recommends against using phantomjs [see] (https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md#setting-up-phantomjs). What is your experience @nilesh? Should I be worried?

Comment: I used PhantomJS for smoke tests and quick response since its faster than regular browsers because of its headless nature. It worked out well. If smoke tests passed I used to run a full blown functional test suite on a remote selenium grid. Since PhantomJS is not a real browser and mere simulation, I agree with protractor guys, you shouldn't use PhantomJS to certify your build in the final phases. I would suggest use PhantomJS for a small subset of your tests and setup a grid for full functional suite to finally certify builds.

Comment: Thank you for your time @nilesh. Tomorrow I will try to setup phantomjs. Later this year I will try to figure out how run my tests using a selenium grid. Do you recommend any link/blog/book that could explain how to setup the selenium grid (with jenkins..=))?

Comment: Should be pretty straight forward. Here is the doc http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp. You can try sauce labs or browser stack. They might have trial versions for you to test it out